# 3 columns fetched from a different table aren't correctly joining with my main table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This may be a stretch as the LeaseRollup dataset is a bit complex and its hard to make sample data for it so I'll do my best to describe it.

The `LeaseData` dataset contains a bit over 600 records, each one is a lease with its accompanying data. Each record has a `SpaceLeaseID`. I want to join that ID with the `SpaceID` in `LeaseRollup`.

The issue is that `LeaseRollup` has over 30 rows for each `SpaceID`. The top section is filtering for the records that would input the correct values for the 3 columns fetched from `LeaseRollup`.

When I do a left join, the 3 columns are all null. When I do a full join the 3 columns are all null, but the 3 columns from `LeaseRollup` appear in the table with the other columns appearing null. Any ideas?

```
SELECT  *
INTO ##tempRentRoll
FROM dbo.LeaseRollup
WHERE ScenarioID = 'ChildAsset / Most Recent Quarter / All Assets'
  AND SubEntityLevel = 'Space' 
  AND sector NOT IN ('Residential', 'Self-Storage');

SELECT  
    GETDATE() AS RefreshDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i.RowID) RowID,
    i.ReportDate AS ReportDate,
    i.LeaseID AS [Lease ID],
    i.AssetName AS Asset,
    i.TenantName AS Tenant,
    i.SpaceID AS Suite,
    FORMAT(i.SpaceLeaseArea, 'N0') AS [Square Feet],
    FORMAT(i.NetRent_Psf, 'N1') AS [Rent / SF],
    FORMAT(e.RecoveriesCamA_End, 'C2') AS CAM,
    FORMAT(e.RecoveriesTaxA_End, 'C2') AS RET,
    FORMAT(e.OtherIncomeA_End, 'C2') AS [Other Income],
    i.LeaseSignedDate AS [Lease Start Date],
    i.ReportLeaseEndDate AS [Lease Maturity]
INTO 
    rentRollForDYTest
FROM 
    dbo.LeaseData AS i
FULL JOIN 
    ##tempRentRoll AS e ON i.SpaceLeaseID = e.SpaceID;

SELECT * 
FROM rentRollForDYTest

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.LeaseRollup
WHERE ScenarioID = 'ChildAsset / Most Recent Quarter / All Assets'
  AND SubEntityLevel = 'Space' 
  AND sector NOT IN ('Residential', 'Self-Storage')
ORDER BY RowID
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results. Text doesn't communicate data clearly.

Answer (score 0):

From the description is sounds like there may be an issue with joining on SpaceLeaseID and SpaceID.

Left join returning only nulls for those columns means it's not building any matches from the right table, and the full join would return values for the right table but with nulls for the left table columns where the match doesn't work.

Have you checked the formatting/datatypes of the ID's or tested on a smaller scale with two ID's that you know should match?